# Returning false $this->form_validation->run() when there is an empty input type="file"

Tags: php, jquery, css, html, codeigniter

Every time I update my settings and leaving the input type="file" empty. $this->form_validation->run() is always returning false. I did not even use setrules and required it.

Here is my code:

```
public function update_settings()
{
    $this->load->model('bus_owner_model');

    $data = $this->bus_owner_model->get_business_data_id_by_row($this->session->userdata('id'));

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('business_name', 'Business Name', 'required|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('type_of_business', 'Type of Business', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('country', 'Country', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Address', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('city', 'City', 'required|trim|alpha');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address', 'Email Address', 'required|trim|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('contact', 'Contact', 'required|trim|numeric|min_length[7]');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', 'Your email address is already been taken');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == true)
    {
        $config['upload_path']      = "./_profile_images/";
        $config['allowed_types']    = 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png';
        $config['encrypt_name']     = "true";
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);    

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload())
        {

            $this->bus_settings($this->upload->display_errors());
        }else
        {
            $this->load->model('bus_owner_model');

            $file_data = $this->upload->data();

            $data = array(
                'company_name'      => $this->input->post('business_name'),
                'profile_img'       => $file_data['file_name'],
                'type_description'  => $this->input->post('type_of_business'),
                'country'           => $this->input->post('country'),
                'address'           => $this->input->post('address'),
                'state'             => $this->input->post('state'),
                'city'              => $this->input->post('city'),
                'email_address_c'   => $this->input->post('email_address'),
                'contact'           => $this->input->post('contact')
            );

            if($this->bus_owner_model->update_bus($data) == true)
            {
                redirect('bus_owner/bus_settings');
            }else
            {
                $this->load->model('bus_owner_model');
                $this->load->model('user_model');
                $data['latlng']                                     = $this->bus_owner_model->get_latlng();
                $data['get_all_business_data_orderby_total_result'] = $this->bus_owner_model->get_all_business_data_orderby_total();
                $data['get_all_user_data_orderby_total_result']     = $this->user_model->get_all_user_data_orderby_total();
                $data['result_countries']                           = $this->bus_owner_model->get_countries();
                $data['get_business_data_result']                   = $this->bus_owner_model->get_business_data();

                $data = array('error' => 'unable to upload files');
                $this->load->view('site_header', $data);
                $this->load->view('bus_owner_views/left_col_map_single');
                $this->load->view('left_col_static', $data);
                $this->load->view('bus_owner_views/right_col_settings', $data);
                $this->load->view('site_footer');               
            }           
        }                       
    }
}
```

It will then return back to it's page and nothing happened.

Comment: Have you tried to reduce your code to the smallest size that still has a problem? SO is not a "please debug my code for me" site unless you show some effort yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to upload file and apply normal field validation on it.That's the wrong way you are trying to validate.Because file field have different behaviour than normal input field.Try this way only for file field.

```
public function update_settings()
{
   $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

             redirect('bus_owner/bus_settings');
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        }
}.
```

For more details goto [link](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html).

Comment: Do I need two form for this? ex. (form for file upload) and another form for the update details?

Comment: No only one form , the above code only for the file upload.Add above code to your function.But use this for form  form_open_multipart() or enctype.